# How to detect concurrent dates

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, date, date-range

I need an algorithm which looks simple, but I still can't think about a well optimised way to do to do this.

I have the following json object:

```
  [
        {
            "start": "2000-01-01T04:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2020-01-01T08:00:00.000Z"
        }, {
            "start": "2000-01-01T05:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2020-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
```

As you can see, the second object  is inside the range of the first.  **I need to iterate over this array and return which date ranges are conflicting(overlaping). In other words: each date range could never overlap one of the others. **

**Example**

```
overlaping date ranges
 [
        {
            "start": "2000-01-01T04:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2020-01-01T08:00:00.000Z"
        }, 
       {
            "start": "2010-01-01T05:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2020-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"
        },
       {
            "start": "2010-01-01T05:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2020-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]

No overlaping dates
 [
        {
            "start": "2000-01-01T04:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2001-01-01T08:00:00.000Z"
        }, 
       {
            "start": "2002-01-01T05:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2003-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"
        },
       {
            "start": "2010-01-01T05:00:00.000Z",
            "end": "2020-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
```

My project is in ruby on rails right now, but I just need an idea how to implement the algorithm so, any high level programming language would be good.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: iterate over the array and use `Date.parse`.

Comment: Yeah, the convert is not the problem. I found the following link with a solution: https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/07/check-for-date-range-overlap-with-javascript-arrays-sorting-and-reducing/ I didn't know the english word for that which is "Overlap"

Comment: You need to clarify "which dates are conflicting" (preferably by editing the question). Whenever you give an example it is helpful to show the desired result (as a Ruby object).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Both items in the array are conflicting already. I just inserted two. The first is between 4 and 8, and the second is between 5 and 7. I thought it was clear enough. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know what "conflicting" means. I didn't downvote but I expect that some readers who did don't know what it means either. The solution is not to define "conflicting", it is to not use the word at all. Moreover, assuming your first step is to create an array from the JSON string, it would be simpler to just refer to the array and not mention JSON at all...

Comment: ... I'm guessing your question is: given an array `dates` of time ranges (with times expressed as strings), some of which may be overlapping, I wish to return an array `arr` of non-overlapping `DateTime` ranges such that each time covered by one or more of the ranges in `dates` is covered by one range in `arr` and each time that is covered by one range in `arr` is covered by at least one range in `dates`. Or perhaps with the proviso that if a range `r1` in `dates` overlaps a `r2` in `dates`, each date covered by `r2` is covered by `r1`. You need to state the problem along similar lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Detect a DateTime Object Covered By a Range

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but this seems relatively straightforward to me. The trick is to convert your Hash values into [DateTime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) ranges that can take advantage of the built-in [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) method.

Consider the following:

```
require 'date'

dates = [
  {:start=>"2000-01-01T04:00:00.000Z", :end=>"2020-01-01T08:00:00.000Z"},
  {:start=>"2000-01-01T05:00:00.000Z", :end=>"2020-01-01T07:00:00.000Z"},
]

# convert your date hashes into an array of date ranges
date_ranges = dates.map { |hash| hash.values}.map do |array|
  (DateTime.parse(array.first) .. DateTime.parse(array.last))
end

# compare sets of dates; report when the first covers the second range
date_ranges.each_slice(2) do |range1, range2|
  puts "#{range1} covers #{range2}" if range1.cover? range2
end
```

Because Range#cover? is Boolean, you might prefer to simply store dates which are covered and do something with them later, rather than taking immediate action on each one. In that case, just use [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-select). For example:

```
date_ranges.each_slice(2).select { |r1, r2| r1.cover? r2 }
```

Comment: Cool, It worked fine. I am looking at the performance of the cover method right now. But it worked well. Also, the database approach in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63366490/2510464 Will be useful in the future =). Thanks

Comment: This assumes that ranges will already be sorted and any overlaps will be next to each other, for example it wouldn't work if the fifth element in the list overlaps with the first

Comment: Also, be careful with `cover?`. This method is not "intersects with"-kind. It's not bi-directional. `(1..5).cover?(2...4)` and `(1..5).cover?(2...6)` are TRUE, but `(1..5).cover?(0...4)` and `(1..5).cover?(0...6)` are FALSE even though they clearly do intersect. Unless your data is properly prepared for this in mind, you may need to `if (range1.cover?(range2)) || (range2.cover?(range1))` instead. YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

First, we can transform the list of hashes to parse the dates into `Date` objects:

```
require 'date'

dates = input.map do |hsh|
  hsh.transform_values { |str| Date.parse str }
end
```

Now we can use a nested loop and use [`Range#cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) to find if there are duplicates:

```
conflicting = dates.select.with_index do |date, idx|
  [date[:start], date[:end]].any? do |date_to_compare|
    dates.map.with_index.any? do |date2, idx2|
      next if idx == idx2 # so we don't compare to self
      (date2[:start]..date2[:end]).cover?(date_to_compare)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is more what I was thinking about. I didn't know that the term I was looking for was overlap instead of concurrent. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

Shove the data into a database using BTREE index on the date fields.  Let the DB do the work for you.

Lets say we have the following table:

```
TABLE myDate {
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED, date_start DATETIME, date_end DATETIME
}
```

Then you want BTREE (or BTREE+) index on date_start and date_end, and HASH index on id.

Once these are in place, feed your table the data, and perform the following select statement to find times that overlap:

```
-- Query to select dates that are fully contained such as in the example (l contains r):
SELECT l.id, l.date_start, l.date_end, r.id, r.date_start, r.date_end
FROM myDate l JOIN myDate r ON (l.date_start < r.date_start) AND (l.date_end > r.date_end);

-- Query to select dates that overlap on one side:
SELECT l.id, l.date_start, l.date_end, r.id, r.date_start, r.date_end
FROM myDate l JOIN myDate r ON ((l.date_start < r.date_start) AND (l.date_end > r.date_start)) OR ((l.date_start > r.date_start) AND (l.date_end < r.date_start));
```

Comment: This looks awesome

Answer (score 0):

Those strings look like ISO 8601 format. You should be able to easily parse that into a Date/DateTime/orsimilar object. Check the docs about those classes, it will be shown there show you cn do that. Then, after parsing into objects, you should be able to compare those date objects simply with </<=/>=/> operators. With this you will be able to compare starts/ends, and you will be able to determine if a date X is:

(a) fully before the other one
(b) startsbefore and ends within the other one
(c) fully within the other one
(d) startswithin and ends after the other one
(e) fully after the other one
(f) is longer and fully contains the other one

I think that's all possibilities, but you better double-check that. Draw them all on time axis if needed and see if there are any other possibilities.

When you have code that can do this classification, you're good to go and implement rest of the logic that bases on that.

> but I still can't think about a well optimised way

don't. Write it first in any way, just to get it working and reliable. Understand the problem from the beginning to the end, thoroughly. Then measure its speed and quality. If it's not good, then write a v2 version based on a first-whatever-guess regarding speed/quality observations. Measure and compare. If it's still not good, then collect code, data sets, measurements, make sure test cases and measurements are repeatable by readers that don't have your computer&network&passwords&etc, and then explain the problem and about how to fix/optimize that. Without all of this, asking about "optimization"*) mostly leads to pure guessing.

*) OFC assuming that "well optimized way" wasn't an empty buzzword, but a real question re performance

Comment: Yes, it was regarding performance. I could do  it doing a lot of iterations but I believe it could be a lot better

Comment: @TalesMGodois great! then read the bottom half of my answer, that one starting with "don't". These things are pretty important in optimization. That's why in the "bottom part" I'm asking you to "collect (...)". Otherwise you either waste people's time leaving them guessing and winkling out the specifics from you via comments or elaborate answers, or you risk getting "solutions" that do look like working, but not really do..

Comment: @TalesMGodois: I see that you've accepted that each_slice(2) answer. Have you seen how each_slice works? [see here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice). If it really works good for you (I somewhat doubt, did you test it well? see MaxPleaner's comment), then you've forgotten to say that your data is already prepared in some way (i.e. sorted, etc). That's what I meant. Also,you now write `I could do it doing a lot of iterations but I believe it could be a lot better` - that's another example, you didn't even state in the question that you want to fight with the "lot of iterations"

Comment: @TalesMGodois re "a lot of iterations" (1) doesn't mean that the algo is slow on your data (2) "iterations" may be well-hidden in shorter code, or traded-off for memory ('each_slice' answer again, .map, date_ranges, .each_slice, are they lazy or not? will they fit in memory? we have no idea how large your datasets are, (...)),  (3) doesn't really mean much (that answer mentioning doing the work via DB with a BTREE index, how many "iterations" you'll get there?). And so on...

Comment: Understood. I think I really think I should edit the question to make this easier to understand what I really wanted. Do yo I think I should keep the old text and add an update section after all comments? I understand a bit better about how to write better question. But I think I got where I wanted, Like, my purpose with this question weren't just get the algorithm. But get ideas. And I really liked the answers, help me to think I'm different approaches. I had one solution in my mind, I could just pasted it and look for improvements, bit I didn't wanted to get results close to mine

Comment: I really wanted to know if I was too far of a good solution, Like, I know that there are a lot of variables on this decision, like you said, memory, dataset length, and so on. I thought that if I pasted an algorithm here, I would orientate more than I wanted to this particular problem. Does it make sense? Our brains can trick us, I just want more overviews, and I believe I get it. The database option for example, I didn't used it in my software, but I never thought about that, even if I am not using it right now, this can help me and others in the future.

Comment: The question that I marked as the right one, had become the basis of my code, but with some changes. I will paste the result asap. Best, and thanks @quetzalcoatl (not sure if it's my phone, but it's not marking you).

Comment: @TalesMGodois: It's not marking me, because you're replying directly to my answer, so I get notified automatically, no need for marking :) You know, if you got your thing solved, then it's probably not worth doing anything now. If the question were really bad, then yeah. But it's not. You got some answers, and now editing/rewriting the question to large extent could make those existing answers sound odd. If the question were totally missed, it's sometimes better to delete it and post another improved.. But again,it's not. Even if it gets closed, it's fine, as you got hints.So let's leave it :)